# How to assign forkJoin data to variables?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have the follow class:

```
class ExampleComponent {
    application: Application = new Application();
    company: Company;
    bank_account: BankAccount = new BankAccount();
    contact: Contact;
    director: Director = new Director();
    websites: Website[] = [];
    files: DirectorFile[] = [];
    director_files: DirectorFile[] = [];

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getApplication();
    }

    getApplication() {
        forkJoin([
             this.exampleRepo.getApplication(),
             this.exampleRepo.getCompany(),
             this.exampleRepo.getBankAccount(),
             this.exampleRepo.getContact(),
             this.exampleRepo.getDirector(),
             this.exampleRepo.getAllWebsites(),
             this.exampleRepo.getAllFiles(),
             this.exampleRepo.getDirectorFiles()
         ]).subscribe(
             (data: [
                 Application,
                 Company,
                 BankAccount,
                 Contact,
                 Director,
                 Website[],
                 DirectorFile[],
                 DirectorFile[]
             ]) => {
                 this.application = data[0];
                 this.company = data[1];
                 this.bank_account = data[2];
                 this.contact = data[3];
                 this.director = data[4];
                 this.websites = data[5];
                 this.files = data[6];
                 this.director_files = data[7];
             }
         );
    }
}
```

And I get the following error:

```
error TS2345: Argument of type '(data: [Application, Company, BankAccount, Contact, Director, Website[], DirectorFile[], DirectorFile[]]) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: (Observable<Application> | Observable<BankAccount> | Observable<Contact> | Observable<Company> | Observable<Director> | Observable<DirectorFile[]> | Observable<Website[]>)[]) => void'.
  Types of parameters 'data' and 'value' are incompatible.
    Type '(Observable<Application> | Observable<BankAccount> | Observable<Contact> | Observable<Company> | Observable<Director> | Observable<DirectorFile[]> | Observable<Website[]>)[]' is not assignable to type '[Application, Company, BankAccount, Contact, Director, Website[], DirectorFile[], DirectorFile[]]'.
      Property '0' is missing in type '(Observable<Application> | Observable<BankAccount> | Observable<Contact> | Observable<Company> | Observable<Director> | Observable<DirectorFile[]> | Observable<Website[]>)[]'.
```

If I don't specify the types in the data and just writes: `data => {...}` I get the following error:

```
error TS2322: Type 'Observable<Application> | Observable<BankAccount> | Observable<Contact> | Observable<Company> | Observable<Director> | Observable<DirectorFile[]> | Observable<Website[]>' is not assignable to type 'Application'.
  Type 'Observable<Application>' has no properties in common with type 'Application'.
```

If I remove the array from `forkJoin` and just adds the 8 requests as single parameters, I am able to assign data to the variables, but then I get an error from linter and rxjs saying that forkjoin with resultSelector is deprecated.

Any idea to how I can assign the data to my variables. How do I destruct the array of Observables to objects?

Comment: You don't need to type data, forkjoin has a generic definition. If your service has typed the calls, you should not have any issues. Otherwise, this is a generic typing issue, just make the HTTP calls & the variables match their respective types.

Comment: Try to remove `[]` from `forkJoin` parameters. Change `forkJoin([..])` to `forkJoin(..)`

Comment: @trichetriche If I don't have the types, I get the last error shown in my question

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner It works without `[]` but `forkJoin` with more that 6 parameters is [deprecated](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/observable/forkJoin.ts#L30)

Comment: What if you divide this one into two `forkJoin`s so you could have 4 parameters for each?

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner That might now, is it possible to combine two forkJoins and subscribe to their combined result? But the fact remains that it should be possible to enter an array as a parameter and be able to assign the subscribed data to something.

Comment: I don't see why not. You would end up with two different arrays that you need to map. I think array itself does not work with `forkJoin`. You could try `from` which works with arrays. But I think going with two `forkJoin` would be enough for your case

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner Are you able to make an example?

Comment: @FrankfromDenmark there's no depreciation tag in your link. Also, you're supposed to type your http calls. But anyway, that's just a type mismatch, just add `as any` at the end of every line and your problem will go away.

Comment: @trichetriche Sorry, I get this [deprecated message](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/observable/forkJoin.ts#L29) when I use it. I feel like `as any` defeats the purpose of having types.

Comment: @FrankfromDenmark well then again, you need to **type your calls and your variables accordingly**.

Comment: @trichetriche I'm trying to. My http requests have a type, ex. `getApplication(): Observable<Application> {}` so it's my understanding that when I subscribe to this I should get an `Application` and not an Observable?

Comment: No, you get an observable of a plain object that implements the `Application` interface/class. This isn't an instance of your class, this is a plain object, like a JSON one, but it has all the properties of the class/interface (but not the functions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you subscribe to forkjoin will return an array of the data you called to avoid that and get the single observable you just need to destruct your data array and the intellisense error should disappear, your error was passing the data and not the destructable observable:

```
    forkJoin(
      [
        this.service.getProvince(),
        this.service.getLingueStraniere(),
      ]).subscribe(
      ([Province, LingueStraniere]) => {
        this.province = Province;
        this.lingueStraniere = LingueStraniere;
      }
    );
```

Now your code should be like:

```
forkJoin([
             this.exampleRepo.getApplication(),
             this.exampleRepo.getCompany(),
             this.exampleRepo.getBankAccount(),
             this.exampleRepo.getContact(),
             this.exampleRepo.getDirector(),
             this.exampleRepo.getAllWebsites(),
             this.exampleRepo.getAllFiles(),
             this.exampleRepo.getDirectorFiles()
         ]).subscribe(
             ([
                 application,
                 company,
                 bankAccount,
                 contact,
                 director,
                 website[],
                 directorFile[],
             ]) => {
                 this.application = application;
                 this.company = company;
                 this.bank_account = bankAccount;
                 this.contact = contact;
                 this.director = director;
                 this.websites = website[];
                 this.files = directorFile[];
             }
         );
```

If you not specify the type of the single request before doing the fork, the interface will not work, so in your service where your define your Application http request map the value to his interface:

```
 .pipe(map((value: Application) => value))
```

You need map the data to the interface, or fork join will give you error, if you don't do it, the default type will be any that will contrast the interface type you define in forkJoin.

Comment: I get an array: `(8) [Application, Company, BankAccount, Contact, Director, Array(0), Array(0), Array(1)]` with the following: `0: Application {signer: null, business_model: {…}, metadata: {…}}
1: Company {name: "", registration_number: "", email: "", phone: "", address_line_1: "", …}
2: BankAccount {currency: ""}
3: Contact {name: "", email: "", phone: ""}
4: Director {name: "", social_security_number: "", date_of_birth: "", address_line_1: "", zipcode: "", …}
5: []
6: []
7: [DirectorFile]` 
Then I don't understand why I can't assign `data[0]` to `Application`?

Comment: With an interface: `interface ApplicationRequest {
    application: Application;
    company: Company;
    bank_account: BankAccount;
    contact: Contact;
    director: Director;
    websites: Website[];
    files: DirectorFile[];
    director_files: DirectorFile[];
}` and in subscribe: `this.application_request = data;` and now I get the following error: `Property 'application' is missing in type '(Observable<Application> | Observable<BankAccount> | Observable<Contact> | Observable<Company> | Observable<Director> | Observable<DirectorFile[]> | Observable<Website[]>)[]'.`

Comment: I tried it's work but it's give me the intellisense error, until i get a fix i suggest youu to bypass this error casting your data in subscribe to any.

Comment: This seems to do the trick for now `this.application = data[0] as Application;
                this.company = data[1] as Company;
                this.bank_account = data[2] as BankAccount;
                this.contact = data[3] as Contact;
                this.director = data[4] as Director;
                this.websites = (data[5] || []) as Website[];
                this.files = (data[6] || []) as DirectorFile[];
                this.director_files = (data[7] || []) as DirectorFile[];` not as elegant as I had hoped.

Comment: I just updated my answer, this should fix the ugly casting method

Comment: Still `error TS2322: Type 'Observable<Application> | Observable<BankAccount> | Observable<Contact> | Observable<Company> | Observable<Director> | Observable<DirectorFile[]> | Observable<Website[]>' is not assignable to type 'Application'.` and wasn't able to have arrays within the array like: `website[]`. But thanks for trying! :)

Comment: Strange, i test the code. Try with only 2 Observable and go on to see wich give you the error, or post your interface class

Comment: I update the answer, finally i understand the core of the problem

Comment: Intellisense still reports these as `any` type.

Comment: To solve that create an interface or specify the type of Observable and type of data that you should receive when you subscribe.

Stackblitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z7ez3j

Answer (score 2):

Base type of Objects in JavaScript is function.
In you code you trying to assign "value of type" to "function".
For assing to correct type function in your ***service.ts*** that return Obserbable, should return Observable<Type>.
ex:

```
getApplication(): Observable<Application> {}
```

and after that in **subscribe** function **data** array will be of your type without assign.

```
(data) => {
    this.application = data[0];
    ...
}
```

Comment: In my `ExampleRepo.ts` the requests return Observables like so: `getApplication(): Observable<Application> { }` `getBankAccount(): Observable<BankAccount> {}`

Comment: OK. This is sufficient for the data type to be needed in the resulting array.

Comment: Okay, I have removed the types on `data` but still get the following error: `Type 'Observable<Application>' has no properties in common with type 'Application'.` It's like the data returned is Observables and not assignable data.

Comment: Example from my project 
`const ev1 = this.dictService.getBuildings();  const ev2 = this.dictService.getStages();
forkJoin([ev1, ev2]).subscribe(result => { });`. Return array with correct data types.

Comment: One of service methods `getBuildings(): Observable<ListModel[]> {}`

Comment: and then you are able to set `buildings: ListModel[]` with `this.buildings = result[0]`?